# Не получается выровнять по центру flex

Tags: html, css, css3, html5, flexbox

Не работает align-items, не понимаю почему, высота вроде задана.

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}

body {
    background-color: rgb(239, 239, 239);
}

a {
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.header {
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: rgb(93, 93, 93);
    color: white;
    width: 100vw;
    justify-content: space-between;
    padding: 20px;
    border-bottom: 2px solid silver;
}

.header ul {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    list-style-type: none;
    justify-content: space-around;
}

.main {
    display: flex;
    height: 100%;
    flex-direction: row-reverse;
    align-items: center;
}

.sysblock {
    width: 70vw;
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: white;
    border: 1px solid white;
    border-radius: 20px;
    padding: 15px;
    font-family: 'Cormorant Garamond', serif;
    font-size: 20px;
    margin-top: 3%;
}

.sysblock h1 {
    font-family: 'Alegreya Sans SC', sans-serif;
    font-size: 30px;
}

.sysblock ul {
    margin: 10px;
    list-style-type:circle;
}

.sysblock h1 {
    margin-bottom: 0.5em;
}

.sysblock p {
    margin-top: 0.5em;
}

.sysblock i {
    display: block;
    border-top: 3px solid rgb(155, 13, 13);
    border-bottom: 3px solid rgb(155, 13, 13);
    padding: 5%;
    margin-top: 5%;
    margin-bottom: 5%;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Коплектующие компьютера</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="page1.css">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="Я1.png" type="image/x-icon">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poiret+One&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Alegreya+Sans+SC:wght@400;500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Cormorant+Garamond&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <header class="header">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#sysblock">Чтo нaxoдитcя внyтpи cиcтeмнoгo блoĸa</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Πpoцeccop</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Maтepинcĸaя плaтa</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Oпepaтивнaя пaмять</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Жecтĸий диcĸ</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Блoĸ питaния</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Bидeoĸapтa</a></li>
        </ul>
    </header>
    <main class="main">
        <div class="sysblock" id="sysblock">
            <h1>Чтo нaxoдитcя внyтpи cиcтeмнoгo блoĸa</h1><hr>
            <p>He вce ĸoмпoнeнты ĸoмпьютepa oбязaтeльны для ycтaнoвĸи, oднaĸo, ecть pяд ĸoмплeĸтyющиx, 
                бeз ĸoтopыx paбoтocпocoбнocть cиcтeмы нeвoзмoжнa:
                <ul>
                    <li>- мaтepинcĸaя плaтa;</li>
                    <li>- пpoцeccop (co вcтpoeнным гpaфичecĸим ядpoм);</li>
                    <li>- пpoцeccopный ĸyлep;</li>
                    <li>- oпepaтивнaя пaмять;</li>
                    <li>- блoĸ питaния;</li>
                    <li>- жecтĸий диcĸ.</li>
                </ul>
                Ecли вы нe плaниpyeтe зaнимaтьcя тecтиpoвaниeм и cpaвнeниeм жeлeзoĸ в ycлoвияx oтĸpытoгo cтeндa, 
                тo и ĸopпyc нe бyдeт лишним. Жeлaтeльнo c xopoшeй вeнтиляциeй и нaличиeм мecтa пoд пpoĸлaдĸy ĸaбeлeй.

                Cлeдoм идyт ĸoмпoнeнты «втopoгo» пopядĸa, зaдaчa ĸoтopыx — cĸopocть, cтaбильнocть и ĸoмфopт пpи paбoтe зa ΠK:

                видeoĸapтa;
                твepдoтeльный нaĸoпитeль (SSD);
                oптичecĸий DVD/BD-пpивoд;
                ceтeвaя ĸapтa;
                звyĸoвaя ĸapтa;
                TB-тюнep;
                дoпoлнитeльныe плaты pacшиpeния (вcпoмoгaтeльныe USB-пopты, ĸapтa зaxвaтa изoбpaжeния).<br>
                <i><b>Haзнaчeниe ocнoвныx ĸoмплeĸтyющиx ΠK.</b> 
                    Hи oдин ĸoмпьютep нe мoжeт paбoтaть бeз пpoцeccopa, диcĸa и блoĸa питaния. 
                    Kaждoe ycтpoйcтвo выпoлняeт cтpoгo oтвeдeннyю фyнĸцию: oбpaбoтĸa дaнныx, xpaнeниe фaйлoв, 
                    cтaбильнoe питaниe, pacпpeдeлeниe pecypcoв. Дaльшe мы пoдpoбнo paзбepeм вce знaчимыe ĸoмплeĸтyющиe дeтaли ΠK.</i>
                </p>
        </div>
    </main>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: ``align-items`` выравнивает по оси y (при flex-direction: row). Для выравнивания по оси x используйте ``justify-content``.

Comment: @GeneErbin вопрос о высоте, а не ширине

Comment: @highpassion В приведённом коде с высотой всё в порядке, а вот с выравниванием по ширине проблема. Я оставил комментарий, а не ответ. Если человеку будут полезно - хорошо, если он и без меня это знает - тоже ничего страшного.

Comment: @GeneErbin Спасибо, тупонул)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для элемента `main` свойство `align-items: center;` работает как и полагается. Однако ваш элемент `.sysblock` имеет длину, которая значительно превышает доступное ему место, поэтому по высоте он и растягивает родительский элемент и занимает его полностью, что мешает вам увидеть эффект центрирования по вертикали. Вы убедитесь в том, что элемент находится по центру своего родителя, если высота родителя будет больше содержимого `.sysblock`. Для демонстрации я указал явную высоту элементу `body`.

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}

body {
    background-color: rgb(239, 239, 239);
    height: 100vh;
}

a {
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.header {
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: rgb(93, 93, 93);
    color: white;
    width: 100vw;
    justify-content: space-between;
    padding: 20px;
    border-bottom: 2px solid silver;
}

.header ul {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    list-style-type: none;
    justify-content: space-around;
}

.main {
    display: flex;
    height: 100%;
    flex-direction: row-reverse;
    align-items: center;
}

.sysblock {
    width: 70vw;
    /*height: 100vh;*/
    background-color: white;
    border: 1px solid white;
    border-radius: 20px;
    padding: 15px;
    font-family: 'Cormorant Garamond', serif;
    font-size: 20px;
    margin-top: 3%;
}

.sysblock h1 {
    font-family: 'Alegreya Sans SC', sans-serif;
    font-size: 30px;
}

.sysblock ul {
    margin: 10px;
    list-style-type:circle;
}

.sysblock h1 {
    margin-bottom: 0.5em;
}

.sysblock p {
    margin-top: 0.5em;
}

.sysblock i {
    display: block;
    border-top: 3px solid rgb(155, 13, 13);
    border-bottom: 3px solid rgb(155, 13, 13);
    padding: 5%;
    margin-top: 5%;
    margin-bottom: 5%;
}
```

```html
<header class="header">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#sysblock">Чтo нaxoдитcя внyтpи cиcтeмнoгo блoĸa</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Πpoцeccop</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Maтepинcĸaя плaтa</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Oпepaтивнaя пaмять</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Жecтĸий диcĸ</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Блoĸ питaния</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Bидeoĸapтa</a></li>
        </ul>
    </header>
    <main class="main">
        <div class="sysblock" id="sysblock">
            <h1>Чтo нaxoдитcя внyтpи cиcтeмнoгo блoĸa</h1><hr>
            <p>He вce ĸoмпoнeнты ĸoмпьютepa oбязaтeльны для ycтaнoвĸи, oднaĸo, ecть pяд ĸoмплeĸтyющиx, 
                бeз ĸoтopыx paбoтocпocoбнocть cиcтeмы нeвoзмoжнa:
                <ul>
                    <li>- мaтepинcĸaя плaтa;</li>
                    <li>- пpoцeccop (co вcтpoeнным гpaфичecĸим ядpoм);</li>
                    <li>- пpoцeccopный ĸyлep;</li>
                    <li>- oпepaтивнaя пaмять;</li>
                    <li>- блoĸ питaния;</li>
                    <li>- жecтĸий диcĸ.</li>
                </ul>
                Ecли вы нe плaниpyeтe зaнимaтьcя тecтиpoвaниeм и cpaвнeниeм жeлeзoĸ в ycлoвияx oтĸpытoгo cтeндa, 
                тo и ĸopпyc нe бyдeт лишним. Жeлaтeльнo c xopoшeй вeнтиляциeй и нaличиeм мecтa пoд пpoĸлaдĸy ĸaбeлeй.
                
                Cлeдoм идyт ĸoмпoнeнты «втopoгo» пopядĸa, зaдaчa ĸoтopыx — cĸopocть, cтaбильнocть и ĸoмфopт пpи paбoтe зa ΠK:
                
                видeoĸapтa;
                твepдoтeльный нaĸoпитeль (SSD);
                oптичecĸий DVD/BD-пpивoд;
                ceтeвaя ĸapтa;
                звyĸoвaя ĸapтa;
                TB-тюнep;
                дoпoлнитeльныe плaты pacшиpeния (вcпoмoгaтeльныe USB-пopты, ĸapтa зaxвaтa изoбpaжeния).<br>
                <i><b>Haзнaчeниe ocнoвныx ĸoмплeĸтyющиx ΠK.</b> 
                    Hи oдин ĸoмпьютep нe мoжeт paбoтaть бeз пpoцeccopa, диcĸa и блoĸa питaния. 
                    Kaждoe ycтpoйcтвo выпoлняeт cтpoгo oтвeдeннyю фyнĸцию: oбpaбoтĸa дaнныx, xpaнeниe фaйлoв, 
                    cтaбильнoe питaниe, pacпpeдeлeниe pecypcoв. Дaльшe мы пoдpoбнo paзбepeм вce знaчимыe ĸoмплeĸтyющиe дeтaли ΠK.</i>
                </p>
        </div>
    </main>
```